# Pressure to defend the relevance of one's area of mathematics

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, mathematical-philosophy

I am a set theorist. Since I began to study this subject, I became increasingly aware of negative attitudes about it.  These were expressed both from an internal and an external perspective.  By the “internal perspective,” I mean a constant expression of worry from set theorists and logicians about the relevance of their work to the broader community / “real world”, with these worries sometimes leading to career-defining decisions on the direction of research.

For me, this situation is unwanted. I studied set theory because I thought it was interesting, not because I wanted to be a soldier in some kind of movement.  Furthermore, I don’t see why an area needs defending when it produces a lot of deep theorems. That part is hard enough.

To what degree does there exist, in the various areas of mathematics, a widespread feeling of pressure to defend the relevance of the whole subject?  Are there some areas in which it is enough to pursue the research that is considered interesting, useful, or important by experts in the field?  Of course there will always be a demand to explain “broader impacts” to funding agencies, but I am talking about situations where the pressure comes from one’s own colleagues or even one’s own internalized sense of what is proper research.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92973/discussion-on-question-by-monroe-eskew-pressure-to-defend-the-relevance-of-ones).

Comment: Rather relevant: Melvin Henriksen, [*There are too many B.A.D. mathematicians*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03025252), **Mathematical Intelligencer** 15 #1 (December 1993), 6-9 [freely available version](http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/c/10.htm). See especially the paragraph beginning with "*I was shielded from mathematical bigotry until*" and what follows.

Comment: I am not sure if any of the answers (or the comments in chat) emphasise that this can vary significantly from country to country, and from (mathematical) generation to generation. I am seeing a lot of implicit universal quantifiers and this makes me rather uncomfortable

Comment: (I wrote my comment just before seeing Tim Campion's answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/330238/ which scrupulously _does_ include the caveats I referred to)

Comment: Late to the party, but I note that Davis and Hersh discuss "Hardyism" vs "mathematical Maoism": https://books.google.com/books?id=I1fj_B60fyoC&pg=PA95

Comment: I like this question but I think it is too opinion-based for MO and so I have voted to close.

Comment: @TimothyChow I guess you’re right; it’s entirely about opinions.

Comment: Increasingly, there seems to be a pressure to defend any theorem in a new publication by stating an application.

Answer (score 59):

Overall, people in academia in general and mathematicians in particular are **very lucky** in being free to study (and being able to make a good living) according to the standards of their discipline, without feeling pressure to defend the relevance of their whole subject. In fact even within our disciplines we have a lot of freedom to pursue our individual visions and tastes. (To appreciate how lucky we are compare the situation with musicians, writers, artists, film directors, actors, ...)

Relations with other areas of mathematics or outside mathematics are nice but they are one (and not necessarily a major one) among variety of criteria to appreciate mathematical progress.

I think we do have some duty to try to explain what we are doing outside our community and even outside the mathematical community. (But also this task is easier in some areas and harder in others.)

Another thing that I found useful in similar contexts is the "[sure thing principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sure-thing_principle)". Given an unwanted situation that has no implication on your action why worry about it  <del>at all</del> too much. For example, suppose a paper you wrote and regard as a good paper is rejected. If the rejection was unjust then the conclusion is: "Improve your paper", and if the rejection was just then the conclusion is "Improve your paper".

Comment: +1 but not sure about the last paragraph. The hope is that by discussing it, I can either get some feedback that allows me to understand and accept the situation, or move some logicians to be a little less self-deprecating.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, you are correct! I was carried away a little,  so I updated my answer. Discussions and understanding can be useful even in cases where the sure-thing strategy is a good first approximation.

Comment: Ok but I still don’t get your point. There are logicians who make decisions on the direction of research according whether they think it will be seen as relevant by a larger group. So I’m wondering if i should join them in this practice or whether they should relax and do what’s interesting.

Comment: My point is that you should relax and do what’s interesting and important to the best of your judgement.

Comment: One more comment: With regard to the artists etc, we can be sure that no one will ask them if it has applications.  What counts the most is whether people like it or not, and this can be affected by the amount of expertise or experience of the critic.  The artist (or critics) can also add to a work's appeal by explaining why the work is especially original or was challenging to produce, or just situate in a historical or personal context in such a way that adds interest.  Now these ways of adding to an artistic work's appeal are nearly the same kinds of things that may add to a mathematical

Comment: (cont)... work's appeal.  The artist, though of course typically less well-paid than the mathematician, at least has the benefit of having the modes of valuation of their work fairly transparent, most of which are unapologetically subjective.  The pure mathematician on the other hand has to sometimes deal with "broader impacts" criteria that purport to be objective but which may not be when thoroughly examined.

Comment: If you write a paper you think is good, it gets rejected, and you're confident that the rejection was the result of (say) prejudice against your field or against some group the reviewer rightly or wrongly thinks you belong to -- then the conclusion may be not "improve your paper" but "submit it somewhere else that may use different reviewers".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan What I meant was both "improve your paper" and "submit it somewhere else". Let me emphasize that I think it is ok (more than that, it is part of the job) if people have views and judgement about the relative merit of different fields, different directions, different individuals, and different works.

Comment: When I was a student, applications were looked down upon. "Applied mathematics" was - almost - a dirty word. You wouldn't even dream of defending what you did, theorems should have a value in itself (I was then also interested in applications). It is almost ironic that since then the fashion pendulum has swung to the other side. Today, woe to whom would have no - even so harebrained - application scenario in mind. Today the dirty word is "pure"/"blu-sky" science. Lesson learnt? I sacrifice the occasional lamb(da) to the prevalent fashion, and ignore it as much as possible beyond that.

Comment: In his paper ``[The future of set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211397)'', Saharon Shelah starts with the following:

We shall now try to discuss some relevant axes of interest – so ideally, for each
such axis, the people in the area are divided in a meaningful way (the number of
exclamation marks reflect my view of how much this motivates my own work).

AXIS A: Source of interest

Comment: 1. foundations/applications to philosophy !

2. applications to mathematics !!!

3. historical reasons !!!

4. inner developments !!!!

5. beauty !!!!!!!!!

6. proof with “bones” or at least “meat” !!!!!

7. generality !!!!!!

8. sport (added by popular demand) !!!

Comment: To the last paragraph: the conclusion in each case may indeed be "improve your paper," but that glosses over what constitutes an "improvement" and what kind of "improvements" each situation signals.

Answer (score 41):

These questions can be an opportunity for a bit of soul-searching; that's a not a bad thing once in a while.

You can say that you want to work on whatever you find interesting and no further justification or motivation is needed. And I agree with you and support you in that.

But others can ask why they should give funding and space to support you in doing so, and these are legitimate questions that deserve some answer, since money and research space are limited and desired by many people.

You can answer that, like an artist, you are exploring and creating and this is a valuable activity, and I agree with you there too. But it is more valuable the more people you share it with. Unfortunately, how receptive people are depends on tastes of the moment. So this can become a fashion industry. On the other hand, if you feel there is beauty and value in your area, it may be worth some work to demonstrate this and share with others (or you may call that politics).

You can also answer that your work will be useful to people now or in the future; your area may lead to understandings or breakthroughs with eventual impact on engineering, physics, etc. Given the history of mathematics, you can try to justify that in the long term unforeseen connections often happen.

So, it is not surprising that (to answer your stated question) areas with practical impact, or historically-accepted beauty and merit, find it easier to make these arguments and less pressured to defend their field.

And it can be valuable to ask how your work helps or inspires others, whether in practical or aesthetic senses. I'm not saying it has to do so, especially if your position and funding are already secure. Then do what you want! And I'm not saying one should have this existential crisis every day or even every year, but it can be healthy once in a while.

Answer (score 31):

First let me try to answer the question in an "ideal world", where (in particular) set theory is treated like any other branch of mathematics, and then let me discuss how we might fall short of it.

In an ideal world the question of "What is the importance of your field to the rest of mathematics?" would not get asked so often (unless the field is so small that one has never heard of it before) but the question "What is the importance of your work to the rest of mathematics?" would. The reason for this is that the web of connections between different fields is one of the things that makes mathematics most beautiful.

Of course, this does not mean that if someone's work is not important to other fields of mathematics, mathematicians should reject all their grant proposals and deny their job applications. It just means that connections to other fields of mathematics are one possible very strong selling point. There are a number of reasons that a mathematical theorem can be interesting, of which applications are one.

In my preferred subfield (etale cohomology theory, one of the most fashionable topics of the 1960s), and I suspect in many other fields of mathematics, the way I see it is that there is a technical core of the subject, consisting of works that address the most difficult technical problems or advance the methods of the field, and a surrounding periphery consisting of works which attack specific examples or make only small variations on existing techniques. It is these peripheral works that need applications. (Let me clarify that I am not trying to criticize other mathematicians' works - I am thinking primarily of my own work when I think of work on the periphery, though I am proud of some of my applications.) To convince other mathematicians of the importance of works without applications, one must lean on other points (How long a problem has been open, who has tried and failed, the way it connects different subfields of your field).

An additional advantage for those whose work has applications to other areas of mathematics is that mathematicians in those areas will better be able to understand when they talk about the importance of their work. When someone explains to you work in your field, or that has relevance to your field, you are able to more accurately judge its value. For work in another field, even if it's equally good, you may not be able to verify this yourself. For this problem it seems the only recourse is to try harder to explain your work, for instance using analogies with other work.

Now what may be the problem with set theory?

It seems to me that non-set theorists may have a skewed perception of set theory for a number of reasons:

Some mathematicians view math entirely through the lens of finitary mathematical objects.

One reason is that, because set theory is the foundation of mathematics, most mathematicians work with sets at some point in the research, but typically with sets that are almost entirely dead (i.e. devoid of intrinsic set-theoretic interest). Most mathematicians probably work with only finite sets and sets of zero, one, or two different infinite cardinalities. So if you work with sets you work with something that the mathematician has seen, but not that they have seen be interesting.

Some mathematicians are skeptical of both platonist and formalist philosophical views in mathematics, and take comfort in the fact that their research (and most mathematical research) can in principle be reduced to statements about concrete, finitary objects. For set theory this usually can't be done except in a purely formal way.

Perhaps only because I am optimistic, I think the biggest reason is that mathematicians simply do not understand set theory very much. It is not so transparent to outsiders how a zoo of exotic mathematical fauna arises from the simple concept of size. I think that a lot of mathematicans who are opposed to set theory would be receptive if it were explained to them in an appropriate way. One merely has to examine the top reputation of all time scoreboard on mathoverflow to demonstrate that it is possible for a set theorist, by explaining set theory well, to be popular among mathematicians of all stripes.

Probably the best advice for how to do this is to find the mathematicians in your field who have the most professional success, and try to see how they present themselves to a broader mathematical audience. I attended a beautiful colloquium talk by Hugh Woodin which I thought did a great job of explaining the importance of set theory to non-set theorists without, I think, ever mentioning an application to other branches of mathematics.

Comment: I think it’s fair to ask: what computations are part of your work? I used to ask this when I worked on Wall Street and interviewed mathematicians or physicists, to get an indication for one of the academic skills most directly transferable to a corporate setting. So to Monroe’s students I would say: try the Friedman-esque exercise of determining which sentences with few quantifiers are true in various set theories, or try the Hamkins-esque exercise of illustrating set-theoretic phenomena with tikz — then you can do set theory and pick up some useful transferable skills too.

Comment: I've heard stories where some mathematicians, in hiring committees, would be opposed to promoting set theorists and other people in logic on the basis that "It's not actual math." That appears to be a problem for people working in logic.

Comment: @Mehta I don't think set theory is really a subfield of logic? For logic, I would say something similar, but there are some differences. Areas of logic like model theory have plenty of applications to number theory, algebraic geometry, and other "central" areas of math. Logic and the more logical areas of set theory have the problem that people view them as meta-mathematical, but they don't say anything meta- about most math - but I don't think it's really fair to view most of these works as meta-mathematical in nature, rather studying models etc. as objects in themselves.

Comment: @Will Sawin: while the object of set theory, per se, is not meta at all, I would say that the bulk of the techniques set theorists use -but I may be mistaken- is mainly drawn from logic (tons of model theory etc).

Comment: @WillSawin I certainly consider set theory to be a subfield of logic (and I think arXiv, wikipedia, etc. agree). My understanding is that "logic" as a field of math is generally understood to comprise (at least) set theory, proof theory, computability/recursion theory, model theory, and "nonclassical logic" (which itself has at least proof- and model-theoretic aspects; this is where I would put categorical logic, incidentally, although I think that's much more subjective).

Comment: @WillSawin and set theory has applications to analysis. It was born out of methods to analyze trig series.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for correcting me. I think model theory is actually part of algebraic geometry and representation theory is at least three different fields, so I guess I shouldn't be trusted on the boundaries of mathematical areas.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Does research in set theory from the second half of the 20th century and after have significant applications to analysis?

Comment: @WillSawin Yes. See for example the recent work of Ilijas Farah.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Cool, I know almost nothing of $C^*$ algebras. Anyways the more applications your field has to other areas of mathematics, the more pressure you should personally feel to work on problems that have some relevance to at least one of those applications

Comment: @MattF. I would think that to justify your work to other mathematicians, this advice is not so relevant, because mathematicians would rather see something proved without computations at all.

Comment: @WillSawin But how does one know whether the application is interesting?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Speak to experts in the field the application is in? This is what I do for applications of algebraic geometry to analytic number theory.

Comment: @WillSawin This is precisely the kind of thing I am complaining about, where one works on math not because one finds it interesting in itself, but rather because one is seeking approval from an outside arbiter of mathematical value.

Comment: @MonroeEskew That is precisely the wrong way of looking at it. The relationships and connections between different fields of mathematics are interesting in themselves, but to properly exploit them you need knowledge and good taste on both sides. Unless you have both, you need to borrow them from someone else. It's not about seeking outside approval, but rather about (informally) working together to create something greater than you could individually.

Comment: @MonroeEskew That said, there is no requirement to do this, especially not if your work is interesting in itself. If your work is not directly applicable to other fields then you should feel greater pressure not to avoid the most technical parts of your fields, to work at the greatest possible level of generality, and to do other things that help your theorems fit better into the mathematical tragedy - and this should be a reflection of your personal (pure, uncompromising) mathematical aesthetic.

Comment: @WillSawin +1 and sincere thanks for the advice. I also find connections to other areas really awesome, but it gets me down when people seem to claim there's no intrinsic beauty to set theoretic results and arguments.

Comment: @WillSawin If you think model theory is part of algebraic geometry, you clearly haven't read anything by Shelah!

Comment: I always thought that the widespread indifference to set theory (as well as logic) from general mathematicians was primarily due to an expectation (justified or not) that 'real' mathematics is insensitive to the choice of foundational framework. But maybe that shows my complete ignorance of the actual content of the subject?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don't think this is so different from what I say. The only way to be sure that your statements are independent of the foundational framework is to work with purely finitary objects, or to use sophisticated set-theoretic tools. (And I include as finitary the observation that e.g. some results in analysis about functions on the real numbers can be equivalently stated as asymptotic results about functions on larger and larger finite sets.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn The broader field of logic is often helpful to the mathematics I am familiar with when it is applied to other formal theories than set theory (e.g. o-minimal structures, certain theories describing local fields, the theory of definable sets in algebraic geometry). These results often have massive, purely finitary, applications.

Answer (score 25):

My impression is that the disdain for set theory among other mathematicians is a relatively recent phenomenon. Lauded mathematicians like Erdos, Gödel, Hausdorff, Kuratowski, Steinhaus, von Neumann, or Luzin could be considered set theorists in a broad sense. Certainly, one would expect that Hilbert would have had a deep respect for the modern development of set theory: it's no coincidence that the CH was the first problem.

One thing I think leads people to a negative outlook on set theory is that textbooks in every subject have "set theory introductions" or appendices which clumsily explain some very basic foundations which is then totally irrelevant to the rest of the book, leading people to believe that set theory is just shallow quibbling about axioms or de Morgan's law keeping them away from the truly interesting topic at hand. This tradition seems to trace back to Bourbaki, who funnily enough don't seem to suffer any tarnish for it. I have heard my teachers in other mathematical fields make some spontaneous remark about proper classes--"which you might care about, if you were a set theorist." Like in the same way I might care about numbers if I was a number theorist?

And of course, this bad sociology is not unique to set theory or logic. From what I have read, combinatorics used to be perceived as a second-class subject. This mindset is ingrained in a lot of the writings of Gian-Carlo Rota. And I think the situation has changed, since the subject has gained a lot of prestige in recent years and there have been many connections realized with other branches.

You can see this kind of thing happening all the time in applied mathematics, where fashions change in fast-forward, and the funding with it.

In homotopy theory, Clark Barwick posted a now-removed piece where he said the achievements of the field were being overlooked because of sociological tendencies, such as top researchers content not to publish in prestige generalist journals.

And to give a bit of perspective, I heard a very well-respected researcher recently complain that his field was fading and that his perception was that set theory has all the best people and most exciting progress these days.

I personally find set theory very easy to justify. It has hard problems of great intrinsic interest not too far from the surface (like number theory, in some respects), powerful non-elementary techniques, amazing elegance, and connections with other areas (and probably even more yet to be discovered because of sociological problems). The progress has been enormous but you can still see the chain connecting the classical and modern theory. I think if someone put their mind to it, a set theorist could explain the general picture quite nicely to other kinds of mathematicians, where even people who are informed sometimes have ideas like we are just trying to discover larger and larger cardinals.

In Alain Connes's [advice](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/Companion.pdf) in the Companion, he echoes a quote of Feynman--"why do you care what others think!" Of course, we care about what funding agencies and other evaluators think, but my take-away lesson is that even Connes faced detractors in his career. At the end of the day, it's not worth feeling like we have to continually defend ourselves from the vagaries of the opinions of those who don't (and choose not to!) understand.

Comment: When I was starting graduate studies, Robert Greene told me that he really liked Solovay's result that there is a model of ZF in which all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable. Although this result requires an inaccessible cardinal, Greene said that he liked it because it means that any set of reals which you construct "by hand" must be measurable. So maybe set theory is useful after all :)

Comment: Can you give an example of an open and accessible problem in set theory that you like?

Comment: Kunen's question: Can there be an ultrafilter on $\omega_1$ generated by fewer than the maximum number ($2^{\aleph_1}$) of sets?

Comment: The Kunen example is fair, though not to my taste. The Solovay example is maybe more important, as perhaps the last result in set theory to be widely admired by mathematicians outside the field.

Comment: There are variety of results in set theory that are admired by mathematician outside the field (and should be). E.g., There was a recent result by Maryanthe Malliaris and Saharon Shelah that was rather widely discussed (e.g. by by Gowers https://gowers.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/two-infinities-that-are-surprisingly-equal/ and by Baez (alas over Google+) and in Quanta Magazine) .

Comment: @MattF.: Assume ZF and "If there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$, then there is an injection from $B$ into $A$". Does the Axiom of Choice hold? (Note we require just an injection, not a splitting of the surjection!)

Comment: @GilKalai, it was widely discussed for the poor exposition in popular journals, and one could also say "on peut avoir l'impression trompeuse que le résultat est majeur parce qu'on en parle beaucoup." I read Gowers comments as conditional admiration: "it makes me wonder whether there is a simpler purely combinatorial argument that the set theorists missed", so if no one finds a direct proof soon, then he will admire the result.

Comment: @MattF. : Shelah's "Logical Dreams" lists some open problems or "Dreams" that I think are accessible in the sense of being understandable to a non-set theorist. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211398.pdf  I think that Harvey Friedman's project of finding natural finitary combinatorial statements that require large cardinals is another good example.

Comment: @TimothyChow, Shelah’s dreams are too vague to be good examples here. But I agree that if someone wants to get into set theory, the examples from Bill Chen / Ken Kunen, Asaf Karagila, and you / Harvey Friedman are good places to start.

Comment: Is Turing equivalence universal among countable Borel equivalence relations, takes 5 min to understand. is every hyper-hyper finite Borel equivalence relation hyper-finite. do large cardinals imply there are generic embeddings with critical point omega_1. there are incredible number of easily statable but unresolved questions in set theory.

Comment: does AD imply ordinal determinacy. do any of the Forcing Axioms imply that there is an inner model in which some cardinal is supercompact (if you spend 1 day you could get an understanding what this is asking).

Answer (score 13):

Let me address the very final part of your question, concerning "one’s own internalized sense of what is proper research". I have definitely encountered this form of internal doubt during my years as a researcher, which by the way now lie behind me, since my doubt has gotten the better of me in the end.

John von Neumann wrote (in an essay entitled *The Mathematician*):

> I think that it is a relatively good approximation to truth — which is much too complicated to allow anything but approximations — that mathematical ideas originate in empirics. But, once they are conceived, the subject begins to live a peculiar life of its own and is … governed by almost entirely aesthetical motivations. In other words, at a great distance from its empirical source, or after much "abstract" inbreeding, a mathematical subject is in danger of degeneration. Whenever this stage is reached the only remedy seems to me to be the rejuvenating return to the source: the reinjection of more or less directly empirical ideas.

I know that there are probably many mathematicians who would disagree with the above, but at least Von Neumann openly considered the fact that not all fields of research are inherently valuable. One could argue whether this is solely due to a connection or lack thereof with empirical reality, or whether an inborn sense of mental aesthetics plays a role as well, but this is really beside the point. The point is that there is such a thing as the "value" of a mathematical theorem, or a research direction, or perhaps even an entire research field. Mathematicians do not like such questions, I suspect because they do not like to think about concepts that cannot be clearly defined. And therefore the issue is mostly shoved under the rug, only to be felt by people who are too philosophical in temperament not to be bothered by it.

My area of research was number theory (rational points on varieties), so I was pretty far removed from empirics indeed. So then there was the possibility to justify my research by an appeal to mental aesthetics. (Let's say this is the "Platonic" viewpoint, since we might say that a piece of mathematics is certainly valuable when there is palpable sense that it has an existence of its own, that it was merely waiting to be discovered.) But the problem with an appeal to mental aesthetics is that a big part of it is in the eye of the beholder: **I** can find my research programme interesting, but even when this is the case, it might change the next year. So this can't count for much. So perhaps we are back at Von Neumann's idea that all mathematics is eventually justified by its connection to empirics.

Unless, of course, one's passion or sense of direction is so overwhelming, that questioning the usefulness of your endeavour feels completely beside the point. You do it because, to you, it is obviously the right thing to do, and you would do it no matter what, and you would rather run the risk of spending 8,000 years in Purgatory for wasting taxpayers' money than not pursue your research.

For me though, it was never like that. I constantly felt the pressure to defend the usefulness of my work, and this in turn led me to doubt whether I was actually enthusiastic enough about mathematics generally to be involved in academic research. But I still think yes, I was enthusiastic enough about mathematics generally, but I wasn't sufficiently excited about the questions I was working on, or the answers I was getting. So here probably also your talent comes into the equation. If you are hugely talented, then the mere opportunity of exercising your talent must be a joy in itself. As Edgar Allan Poe writes in *The Murders in the Rue Morgue*:

> As the strong man exults in his physical ability, delighting in such exercises as call his muscles into action, so glories the analyst in that moral activity which disentangles.

Or so I have always believed. (Now I am neither strong nor an analyst, so I can only accept Poe's authority for this.) Anyway, this is all I have to say on the subject. Your question stirred me, so I wanted to give you my thoughts. All the best, René

Comment: My issue with your answer is that I don't think set theory has come to this problem.

Comment: Not set theory as a whole, sure. But I was mainly talking about the crises of conscience that can befall the individual researcher. The field of research of any given set-theorist is usually a lot smaller than the entirety of set theory, so that the relevance of set theory as a whole is in itself not enough to justify one's own particular existence as a researcher. Otherwise you could, by the same argument, justify any type of research activity just by appealing to the relevance of mathematics itself.

Answer (score 12):

It's not just math, I've seen similar stuff in the software and data science industry.  Functional programming, test coverage, Bayesian statistics, and deep learning are just a few areas I've encountered in my short industrial career that bring up strong feelings and flame wars (both across the Internet and within a single company).

---

However, it might be stronger in mathematics, and logic in particular.  I think this is a difficult situation that is driven by two things.  (1) The first is finite resources.  There are only finitely many available positions for graduate students and faculty.  There is also only so much grant money.  This scarcity causes conflict since one must constantly fight for a piece of the pie.  (2) The second is aesthetics.  There are more available problems and research areas out there than one could ever work on.  A lone researcher's work will be lost into the archives, and an overly saturated topic (especially an easy one) could lead to lots of trivial research, much of it being small modifications on the known theory.  Many mathematicians have a personal aesthetic about what is good mathematics, and IMHO, if used correctly, this is very useful for guiding one's field to the problems and tools which are maximally interesting and useful.  But if used wrongly and mixed with lots of ego it will lead to resentment and full-blown public fights.

It is not just set theory, I've seen this in many areas of logic (and I imagine it is also happens in other areas of mathematics).  Here is another example:

Before leaving academics I used to work in algorithmic randomness, a field which gave a rigorous definition of a type of randomness.  I have encountered a lot of open hostility from those who have considered this a sort of "bastardized probability theory".  This wasn't helped by a loud minority (which I very much disagree with) who both think that this actually is both the right canonical definition of "randomness" and that probability theory should be based on this theory.  I also have to admit I have my own internal biases against the field as well.  I think it is focusing too much on the wrong types of problems and I unsuccessfully tried to move the field in a different direction.

I've also seen big fights or snide remarks related to set theory vs category theory, homotopy type theory vs ZFC, reverse math vs constructive math, and the merits of TTE-style computable analysis and proof theory.

---

My best advice is to try to stay above the fray, and don't get sucked into the flame wars.  But also listen openly to the criticisms on both sides and use this to guide your personal mathematical aesthetic.

Answer (score 11):

Back when I was an undergraduate, I took two ‘special study’ semester classes in surreal analysis that were structured as two-on-one meetings once a week in my (excellent) analysis professors office, with a great algebra teacher present and adding much needed insights.

We were working through Alling’s book on the subject, which mentions various different set theories and some small large cardinals, so I grabbed some relevant books from the library before one of our meetings — one of the books was ‘The Higher Infinite’ by Kanamori.

My analysis professor saw me reading it in the waiting room outside his office before the meeting and immediately stopped and asked me if I’d ever read any H. P. Lovecraft — I hadn’t, but I was a fiction fan and asked him what prompted the question. He remarked that Lovecraft incorporated a tome into many of his works called the [necronomicon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon), a book containing secrets about reality not meant for mortal eyes. Any person who cracked this book open was rewarded with insanity and subjected to forces beyond our mortal perception, inevitably resulting in their destruction/bodily consumption etc.

He said (with a laugh) that Kanamori’s book had always reminded him of a real life version of the necronomicon, and to be wary. My algebra professor had joined us at this point and heartily agreed — both of these professors were very bright and successful in their own fields, with my analysis professor having tenure and good clout within the department. That both of them responded this way to ‘real’ set theory left a striking impression on me, that it was viewed in some sense as ‘gibberish containing inscrutable truths’ to other intelligent mathematicians in much the same way that all of mathematics is viewed in this way by the general public, and I think this is related the the stigma that exists towards the subject.

(I don’t mean to cast aspersions on either professor should they read this post, I just thought it was a relevant anecdote :)

Comment: Isn't this rather an illustration of the fact that some people think that set theory, or just a specific book in set theory, is difficult to understand? I think I have had this conversation with brilliant mathematicians about other topics, including homological algebra, category theory and some topics in algebraic geometry, analytic number theory... On the other hand,I have had other conversations where the relevance of studying some problems in set theory was questioned, but I dare say this was mostly out of unfamiliarity with problems in set theory and the beauty of set theoretic venture.

Comment: @nombre I can see getting that impression from the above exchange, but after our meeting that day we talked at some length about his views on logic and set theory. He said that ever since grad school (which was in the 60s for him) he had gotten the impression that logicians and set theorists were striving towards some greater sense of 'truth' than the rest of mathematics, in a way that came across as overreaching and off-putting -- I think that this 'philosophical disagreement' with the purpose of an entire discipline was limited to logic and set theory.

Answer (score 10):

This kind of issues plagues the whole of mathematics and theoretical computer science (TCS), where short-term fads (one can only get grants in "impactful" areas - this is certainly the case in many European countries) and internal politics (why would we hire that person, we'd rather increase our influence by hiring someone very close to our "own" area) dictate funding decisions.

It's basically a fashion industry now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

Outside of obviously-applicable subjects,

> The complete absence of pressure to defend the value of one's work is a sign of at least one of the following.
>
> 1. Great luxury (you can do what you want without answering to anyone)
> 2. Total irrelevance (nobody believes a good answer exists, so they don't ask)
> 3. Institutional corruption (the community knows it is open to severe legitimate challenge, and would like to keep things quiet)
> 4. Intimidation (e.g. students or subordinates afraid to question the professor on why X is being done/taught)

A healthy research program should welcome inquiries and have convincing answers.

Inability to answer "why this?" questions is a sign of problems.

The *desire* to never be confronted with such questions is often a means of denial and postponing change.  Of course, avoiding change from within leads to change being imposed from outside, either bluntly or through slow attrition.

As for set theory, it is clearly an outlier field by objective standards as well as in the more sociological judgements of fashion that were noted in the question.  But if the sociological position doesn't improve from decade to decade, is it really correct to call the perception mere "fashion"? The reputation of subject X within mathematics is sometimes much different than the honestly defensible value of X.  Still, there is quite a bit of correlation, and these are the persistent opinions of people who are not expert but not ignorant either (they are mathematician after all), and would certainly have been able to read and appreciate a substantial (i.e. engaging realistically with criticisms) account of the value of set theory had such a thing been published in the past 50 years.

Comment: This does not look like most first posts to MO...if it is an experienced user posting under a new name, it may indicate that feelings of intimidation are widespread.

Comment: probably my reading skills are lacking but I can not understand the point of this argument. Is set theory clearly an outlier field? Isn't the research on the geometric Langlands program more useless than that? Or, say, gauge-theoretic invariants in differential topology a la Donaldson? Quite a lot of mathematical fields are utterly useless for the society at large. I would understand if you suggested that we should stop funding all of them, but set theory does not seem that special in this regard. Could you clarify?

Comment: @schematic_boi  .... There is a broad range of standards of value from the stringent "does it cure cancer by next Wednesday" to the lax "is it of interest to the 50 people worldwide who publish on it".  There are many such criteria, some of them totally objective or even numerical, that GL, GT and other mainstream research areas of mathematics would pass and set theory (of the same vintage) would fail, and no such tests that I can think of where the reverse would be true.  In that sense set theory it is an outlier.

Comment: Regarding "and these are the persistent opinions of people who are not expert but not ignorant either", are we talking about people who studied forcing? inner model theory? pcf theory? any post-1960s set theory? I heard distinguished mathematicians (the kind that have multiple Annals publications) ask questions that would embarrass an undergrad who took a first course in axiomatic set theory. With all due respect, why should we take their judgement seriously?

Comment: You can quantify the relationship between fields of math as in the graphs at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2259/visual-representation-of-mathematical-research-interrelationships or http://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=mathoverflow.net&size=32 -- that quantification may show set theory as an outlier, but no more than other fields.

Comment: @Haim, you ignore the people making hiring and funding decisions at your own risk.

Comment: @MattF. My comment was addressing the claim that if mathematicians have a persistent opinion about set theory, then they're probably right ("they are mathematicians after all", in the words of the above answer). Of course, as a set theory postdoc, I bow down to the gods of the hiring committees and pray that they will be kind enough to accept my descriptive set theoretic offering.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist what are these supposed tests of value?

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist Can you give any examples of measuring value besides curing cancer and counting the number of people who care? What about a detailed introductory talk explaining why this specific math is interesting and challenging in itself? Have you never been fascinated by pure mathematics itself? And if you have, how do you explain why set theory is not worthy of that kind of awe while other pure areas are?

Comment: @Haim, I think that for people who mathematically matured in other fields, and then take some time to read books and articles in set theory, it often (and legitimately) reinforces their feeling that set theory is relatively disconnected from normal mathematics.  My own experience was the strong impression that the sort of  arguments typically given for relevance of set theory are largely dependent on intellectual intimidation (such as the idea that significant expertise is necessary to confirm or deny the initial intuition of disconnection) or are simply false when examined in detail.

Comment: @Haim, it was nowhere stated that the persistent opinion of mathematicians is "probably right".   The actual idea was that this is a nontrivial phenomenon that cannot be dismissed as pure ignorance given the level of information that many of those critical/unimpressed do have, the amount of time elapsed, and the extensive opportunity during that time for set theorists to have come up with one or more documents that would alter the perceptions of some of the silent but critical majority.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I think that you're giving those mathematicians too much credit. Non-logicians who bothered to seriously study some nontrivial post-1960s set theory are extremely rare (I'll be happy if anyone can prove me wrong). And yes, sometimes it takes significant expertise in order to confirm the connections between set theory and mainstream mathematics. Two examples that come to mind are the works of Farah connecting set theory to operator algebras, and the recent monograph of Larson and Zapletal, connecting set theory to many topics in mainstream mathematics.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist (continued) Such results seem to suggest that the deep connections between set theory and mainstream mathematics are out there and are (mostly) yet to be uncovered. The only thing that we need is more mathematicians with a deep understanding of both set theory and other branches of mainstream mathematics, and this combination seems to be quite rare.

Comment: @Haim, the typical situation when one subject has connections to others, is that there are many points of contact at different levels of accessibility. If someone asks the connection of algebraic geometry to other math and the only answers are "we can't even begin to tell you until you read EGA" that would arouse justified suspicion.  In fact, there are many down to earth explanations that do not require either EGA or comprehension of the specific proof techniques, because math.AG overlaps heavily with math.nonAG in its nontrivial objects of interest.  Very different situation for math.ST.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I respectfully second Monroe's request that you explain what objective tests of value you are referring to.  I don't mean to badger you about it, but it sounded like you had something particular in mind, and I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, e.g. "how many cases are there of a construct that appears both in theory X and another theory Y, that are considered nontrivial from the perspective of both X and Y".   Most robust mathematical theories have numerous examples of this with multiple $Y_i$, but rare for set theory.   "Applications of X to questions stated without words from X"; same issue.  Or take any other criterion in which X is a variable, let X = set theory, and see what happens vs other theories. Ordinary math deals with objects that are set-theoretically trivial; that is one reason for lack of interaction.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, I had in mind to take any objective criterion or metric for valuing a theory (call it X) that can be applied to any given X in mathematics.  Every one I can think of either gives the same answer for set theory as any other theory, or the other theories pass and set theory fails.  Nothing where ST passes and others fail.  Do you know any counterexample?

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist These seem like reasonable tests.  I'm not knowledgeable enough to determine whether set theory would underperform on them, and I admit that it seems possible.  I wouldn't call these tests entirely objective -- especially the first one, because "nontrivial" seems subjective.  Have these tests ever been run in a systematic way, or are you just making an informed guess about what the results would be?  I don't quite agree with your last statement.  Real numbers and sets of real numbers are not set-theoretically trivial, for example.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, the real numbers *are* trivial in most other subjects one might try to intersect with set theory, so they are not a case of mutually nontrivial overlap as in the stated criterion ("...from the perspective of both X and Y").  Are there sets of real numbers generated outside set theory that are set-theoretically nontrivial, such as it being non-obvious whether they satisfy the Continuum Hypothesis?   I thought that sort of thing is ruled out by large cardinals.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist Analytic sets of real numbers can appear outside of set theory, and I would not consider them to be set-theoretically trivial objects.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I mean actually occuring specific individual objects , not any hypothetical  element from some family (such as analytic sets) that occur in some theorem.   For example, the sphere occurs in both geometry and in topology and is an interesting non-trivial object from the point of view of both theories.  IIRC it is a theorem that under large cardinal assumptions any constructible subset of reals satisfies CH and much more.

Comment: A related observation is that even in the most famous example of applied set theory, Solovay's theorem that ZF+DC cannot prove existence of a nonmeasurable set of reals, there isn't any known example of a specific set (at least none from outside set theory, abbreviated FOST) that was not obviously measurable by dint of being produced by operations that are well known to preserve measurability.  At the level of specific objects FOST it is hard/rare (and in some contexts impossible) to find set theoretic questions that have non-trivial answers.

Comment: Look at the graph theory example here.  https://gowers.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/determinacy-of-borel-games-i/

Comment: Here’s another: https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=1435-9855&vol=6&iss=3&rank=1

Comment: And what about the connections between topology and set theory? Set theory has a lot to say about general topology, and topological notions and techniques are used a lot for purely set theoretic goals, like understanding forcing or properties of ultrafilters.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, general topology is largely in the same boat with set theory, and bears the same relationship to topology as set theory to mathematics.  Same with infinitary combinatorics/games versus finitary  combinatorics and game theory.  It might be more accurate to call these subjects "set theoretic", rather than general or infinitary, topology/combinatorics/game theory.  The distinction exists on a technical level and perhaps can be formalized as reliance on particular axioms (AC, GCH, AD...), the ubiquity of set-theoretic independence and "large" objects, or other contrasts to core math.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist One gets the sense that whenever a connection between set theory and  another mathematical topic is found, there will be a group of people who just declare that topic to be “too set theoretical.” Look at the reception of Shelah’s solution to the Whitehead problem.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, yes, but I think these are valid technical/formalizable distinctions arising out of mathematical practice, and what you might perceive as prejudices and shifting goalposts reflect the fact that most haven't taken the trouble to contemplate the details of the divide until presented with examples (and lack language to do it formally).  Since the abstract period of 1920-50's that birthed set theory there has been an evolution toward definitions and objects/methods that both cover the cases of interest *and* exclude the ones of noninterest. Set/gentop is from the older tradition.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist That certainly doesn’t seem to be the case with category theory and algebra.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist also you’re not responding to the Foreman-Weiss work. And what about Farah/Weaver’s solutions to the problem about automorphisms of the Calkin algebra. Why didn’t the functional analysts exclude that problem from being of interest? Probably because by Gödel, independence can never be removed.

Comment: @MonroeEskew,  category theory was born "applied" from materials in algebraic topology, and has remained close to it ever since (higher category theory = homotopy theory, more or less), with algebraic geometry and logic as further application areas added later.  That said, it does suffer from a partly justified perception as "generalized abstract nonsense", and the set theoretic parts of algebra (big abelian groups, things strongly dependent on AC or GCH, etc) are also in the aforementioned boat.  I think it comes down to the formalizable distinctions being played out.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I’m saying that category theory does not seek to reduce generality.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, category theory reduces generality by imposing (and teaching us how to look for) functoriality conditions that make constructions "smooth in parameters", and focusing attention on what properties (e.g., what kind of morphisms) are needed to get a good theory.  Choosing the objects and morphisms to get a good theory rather than seeking a general theory of all objects.  This is opposite to the older seek-maximum-generality heuristic.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, re: Whitehead problem, I'm too young to know how Shelah's solution was received.   I'd be surprised if anyone denied it was a brilliant, breakthrough result.  On the other hand, having looked at the paper and some related ones a while ago, it's not clear to me that it says anything in concrete cases, as Whitehead property is true under fairly general conditions. Independence is from maybe too-strong notion of freeness (vs, say, aleph-one version).  My sense was that some people in set theory have a wishful idea this paper is a magic bullet to kill question of ST's applicability.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Regarding the other papers, digesting any one to the point of having an opinion takes time, and the set theory often arises from details of the formalization rather than establishing a robust bidirectional road between two subjects.   There are genuine formal dividing lines of constructiveness, cardinality, and other forms of logical/set-theoretic complexity, with a lot of traffic within both sides of the divide and relatively little across it. Sociological implication is that there may be two "math universes" mostly disconnected from each other, but sharing office space.

Comment: Regarding Shelah’s result, it is quite ironic that you claim that the algebraists had the wrong notion of freeness and instead we should use one defined in set-theoretic terms.

Comment: Regarding the Foreman-Weiss paper(s), they used descriptive set theory to show that a very mainstream classification program in dynamical systems could not succeed as originally conjectured. I don’t know how this fits with your “dividing lines.” The point is that there was a problem from “real math” that logical techniques had to be used for, and it was done by well-regraded mathematicians and published in prestigious journals. This should be enough—you shouldn’t then go searching for ways to discount it.

Comment: 1) I did not comment on the Foreman-Weiss result, never mind "go searching for a way to discount it".     2)  you describe their work as a surprising revelation from set theory that a program could not succeed "as conjectured", but what they say in the introduction to their paper is that evidence had been accumulating for an impossibility result, and they do not mention any positive conjecture (which one would expect them to cite, had it existed and they disproved it).   3) I do not see what in the paper uses the sort of large/nonconstructive structures typical of ST "dividing line".

Comment: In other words, you picked as an application a paper that makes no apparent use of large structures, forcing, axioms beyond ZFC, axioms of any other system of set theory, or models of set theory. Maybe there is something buried in the references that does use those things?

Comment: That is, the historical names for various subjects (such as general "topology" or descriptive "set theory") may not match the later evolution of those fields or precisely describe the situation for purposes of the current discussion.  I have no idea what is in the references to the F-M paper and whether it involves independence phenomena or the other hallmarks of set theory listed in preceding comment(s), but from what is visible in F-M it seems consistent with all that I wrote about a "dividing line".

Comment: @MonroeEskew, your examples in these recent comments could be the core of an expository paper, and I would want to read it.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, The superficially set-theoretic terminology "aleph-one free" (abelian group) is shorthand for a very simple condition: *every countable subgroup is free*.  If you want to cite every appearance of the word "countable" in mathematics as a use of set theory that might have been a valid point 100 years ago but I don't think it works for mathematics in our lifetimes.  What is true is that independence is often the result of definitions that are stronger/weaker than what is used in practice.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I've been curious lately about whether there are natural, in-the-wild examples of non-artificial sets of things of cardinality aleph_1 aside from the obvious ones involving ordinals. It's far from clear to me. However, things like the bounding number b can arise: it is a particular bound in a theorem about the product of CW-complexes.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, I thought a lot of unnecessary uses of CH come from not being careful to state (or typeset in Fraktur) which cardinal characteristic is being used as a bound.     Is "b" the sharp bound for that CW problem (ie., intrinsic to the problem) or something in a particular proof?

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I say descriptive set theory is set theory. I have never seen a real analysis book that talks about complete analytic sets.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist Here’s what I think is going on: You, like many others, just don’t like independence. But Gödel definitively proved that you can never formalize it away, like via your dividing lines. So your only choice is to reject certain math based on a feeling.

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist When you say "general topology is largely in the same boat with set theory" as a response to Monroe's question about connections between those two fields, does that mean you have chosen not to count the connections between them in your tests of value?

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist I have a similar question regarding your statement "There are genuine formal dividing lines of constructiveness, cardinality, and other forms of logical/set-theoretic complexity, with a lot of traffic within both sides of the divide and relatively little across it" (which I don't disagree with): When applying your tests of value, do you count the traffic on both sides equally?

Comment: @NotaSetTheorist yes, it's a sharp bound. :-)

Comment: @MattF. Regarding your speculation "if it is an experienced user posting under a new name, it may indicate that feelings of intimidation are widespread": That is one possibility.  Another is that the user may want to make strong claims without feeling as much pressure to back them up as they would feel when posting under their own name.  For example, I suspect my last two questions may have gone unanswered because I was getting close to exposing a weakness in the user's claims about objective tests of value.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson, I agree; I'd add that asking for back-up on every claim can also be a form of intimidation.

Comment: @MattF.  In general, I suppose it could be.  I don't intend it as such here, if that's what you're insinuating.  My questions have been very reasonable, both in content and quantity.

Comment: i find it really astonishing that some people believe that there is "normal" mathematics and that set theory is not part of it. what is "normal" mathematics? give an exact definition of this boundary and then we will see if there is set theory there or not? this is the good old trap that people like to fall in, it gives people enormous pleasure to draw imaginary boundaries around themselves and then declare that some other people are not in it. if you could explain what math is then you might get a prize in philosophy. if you could explain what mathematicians studies, you will be famous.

Comment: maybe you can say that normal math is everything that mathematicians who have no connection with set theorists study, pretty bad i admit, but i am not really sure how i can save you. this is a deep hole, it is really hard to get out of it. may i point you out to the age old debate in philosophy about analytic and synthetic truths, perhaps that would discourage you to see boundaries between human thought.

Comment: @NotSetTheorist-i read your comments and honestly don't understand what your point is? i mean if i spend my time and give you 100 applications of set theoretic ideas, would this be enough? you just seem to navigate the room in a way that makes set theory outsider.

Comment: Foreman with others solved Von Neumann conjecture about characterizing defeomorphisms of torus. Farah has used the set theoretic axiom known as PFA to show that it implies that all Calkin algebras are inner, and before that C^* algebraists had shown that CH implies otherwise. Rosendal recently showed that all universally measurable homemorphisms are continuous. Woodin solved Kaplanski's problem. there has been number of applications of determinacy in Gower's stuff. how about the really short proof by Kechris that actions of compact groups can be characterized by countable structures.

Comment: recently some CS people have used rank-to-rank embeddings, or rather Laver tables, to come up with a crypto-system. there have been many applications in topology, L-space problem (e.g.), there have been applications in dynamics, in Ramsey theory and etc. i just simply do not know your goal.

Comment: oh, i see, i think i understand what you are saying. in your  theory of usefulness there is a time variable. it is possible for any theory to be useful and have many connections, but that it may stop being useful and connected as time goes on. for example, you seem to be saying that at this time, in the year of 2020, set theory is not well connected, and hence, it is an outside, but in 100 years it maybe the most connected and algebraic geometry maybe completely forgotten, and so set theory will be connected.

Comment: so for example, if somehow analysts discover 0^# and suddenly it becomes the most important number, then set theory becomes the leading subject, boom! and it is also very possible that no one is simply interested in AG from year 2356 onwards, and so AG will become useless piece of garbage. hmm, interesting. i always wonder what makes people feel the need to come up with such utter nonsense, i mean there is so many nice things one can think about, why think about this and produce nonsense?

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few more data points. *Caveat*: I think this is an inherently subjective question, and partly also regionalized. I don't presume that my impressions are necessarily accurate or representative. Actually, I'm kind of hoping that someone might speak up if their impressions contradict my own, because I'd love to adjust my perspective!

As a category theorist, I have often felt as though I need to justify the idea that what I do "is real math". I think this is less the case in many places outside the USA.

I think I've observed a similar anxiety among some model theorists.

As somebody who dabbles in algebraic topology, I have gotten the sense that algebraic topologists by and large don't feel this pressure in the same way.

Comment: Oh, I could tell horror stories about a general math audience comments about homotopy theory :). I feel this is something that happens pretty much to everyone...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQMtp2WxEA4

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned, "why should society give you money to do the research you're doing" is a legitimate question. And, it's legitimate whether the source is internal (other mathematicians) or external (the university), as long as the person doing the asking is genuinely interested in hearing you defend yourself rather than just being snarky.

The trouble, as I see it, is that many of the standard answers do not apply to set theory, at least not directly.

Those who are working on new foundations for mathematics, or trying to unify math and programming in hitherto unimagined ways, can explain that the benefits of their work include better software for doing mathematics, better programming languages, and better tools for automating mundane mathematical tasks. Case in point: I saw a website a few weeks ago where the author had formalized a proof that $3 < \pi < 4$ in Lean; apparently, it was quite a task. And, apparently, to get an extra decimal point required several more *days* of work. This is totally impractical, and such tools need a lot of work. The trouble is, that's not really what set-theorists do, so this style of answer won't work.

Some have mentioned the connectedness of mathematics. The connectedness is certainly wondrous, but set theory seems to be in a league all of its own. It asks its own questions, develops its own tools, and interacts with the rest of math relatively infrequently. So this style of answer also won't work, at least not directly.

With that in mind, I would answer such questions in terms of the *long-run connectedness.* I would say something like this:

> In the 1940's, number theory did not have many known applications.
>   Yet it was interesting, so people studied it in their spare time. Some
>   of the people studying it were so brilliant, they managed to convince
>   society to fund their research, because sure, it had no known
>   applications, but they were obviously having tremendous success
>   solving apparently intractable problems, and there was a feeling that
>   this was important. So universities supported them and they were
>   consequently able to solve difficult and beautiful (though apparently
>   pointless) problems.
>
> The thing is, math seems pointless until you need
>   a hard result that someone else spent their entire career to solve.
>   This only needs to happen once before the natural contempt for people
>   who are wasting their time on overly-abstract problems is replaced by
>   a certain grudging respect. You begin to understand that all
>   mathematicians stand on the shoulders of giants one way or another,
>   and it's hard to know ahead of time whose shoulder you'll need to
>   shift your foot onto to go where you're going.
>
> The kind of set theory
>   I do has few known applications, but the problems are very deep, very
>   hard, and very beautiful. Some of us, those who have a track record of
>   success against such problems, have managed to convince universities
>   to support them so they can carry on their research. This isn't such a
>   crime; there's billions of people in the world, and only a small
>   handful of them are set theorists. The cost to the world of our
>   existence is pretty small. And yes, most of us aren't that clear about
>   what the long-term implications of our work are, but there's a sense
>   that this stuff is important, and we seek to be the shoulder that
>   someone will eventually stand on to go where they're going.
>
> In the
>   1940's, number theory was believed to have little real utility, yet
>   only 30 years later it had emerged as a central theme in public key
>   cryptography, and the internet would be nearly useless without it. I
>   don't know if the same thing will happen with set theory, but maybe it
>   will, and nobody knows ahead of time what ultimate role it will play
>   in our civilization. I do know that if you removed the support from
>   the small handful of people who are working on such problems, there's
>   a real risk that progress in mathematics and technology would
>   ultimately be stifled in a very non-abstract way.
>
> I can't tell you the
>   ultimate role set theory will play in our civilization, in the same
>   way that even the great G.H.Hardy could not predict that number theory
>   would end up playing a fundamental role in the world economy only a
>   handful of decades after his [apology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Apology) for pursuing beauty for
>   beauty's sake. But the cost is tiny, and the cost of removing this
>   small amount of support is potentially huge. Set theory seems
>   disconnected from the rest of mathematics now, true, but the long-run
>   connectedness of things is a difficult thing to comprehend, let us
>   alone predict.

Comment: Do you have a reference for saying that the internet would be nearly useless without public key cryptography?

Comment: @MattF., no, and perhaps I phrased that too strongly. But w/o public key crypto, you can't communicate securely unless you've pre-swapped secret keys, which is impractical. In practice, this means you can't send a password to a website without have it stolen. So websites involving "logging in" don't work. Online banking wouldn't work for this reason. Also, purchasing things online wouldn't work (because someone could pretend to be you and spend your money). Indeed, the only uses of the internet would be fully public uses, like exchanging already-published scientific papers or streaming video.

Comment: @MattF., indeed, even with fully public things, there's a lot of scope for foul play. If I download a document in such a way that there's no crypto involved, anyone in the path between the web server supplying the information and me can modify this document and I'd have no way of knowing. Similarly with downloaded software. W/o crypto, you really can't rely on the validity of the documents you've downloaded or the safety of the software you want to install, and public key crypto is AFAIK needed to make crypto practical - otherwise, you need to pre-swap secret keys, which is impractical.

Comment: If the utility of set theory rests on public-key cryptography, it rests on Solovay too! The original RSA paper (http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf) cites the Solovay-Strassen algorithm for finding large primes.

Comment: @Matt F. the Solovay-Strassen test is of no practical importance: the Miller-Rabin test came along soon afterwards and completely surpasses it (easier math, includes all witnesses from the SS test, and has a higher assured lower bound on the percentage of witnesses: 75% vs. 50%). That it was mentioned in the RSA paper does not mean it matters today. And the work of Solovay on the SS test has absolutely nothing to do with his work in set theory.

Comment: In the highlighted paragraphs on long-run connectedness, the second sentence about people studying number theory in the 1940s in their spare time is rather strange. Artin, Weil, and Chevalley were certainly not thinking about number theory as a spare-time activity. It is like saying Cantor worked on set theory only in his spare time.

Comment: It is also worth keeping in mind that the level of number theory used in RSA is hundreds of years old. The work done in number theory in the 1940s has nothing to do with RSA, but your long-term connectedness essay seems to suggest to the non-expert that it is part of what matters in RSA.  The first time 20th-century math mattered in cryptography was the introduction of elliptic curve cryptography in the 1980s, which uses elliptic curves over finite fields (not $\mathbf C$). The development of algebraic geometry over finite fields beyond individual examples goes back to the 1920s and 1930s.

Comment: @KConrad, indeed -- what does it say about an argument for set theory that when it tangentially involves a noted set theorist, it involves his non-set-theoretic work?

Answer (score 6):

Timothy Gowers' essay,

> Gowers, William Timothy. "The two cultures of mathematics." *Mathematics: Frontiers and Perspectives* 65 (2000): 65.
>   [PDF download](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/2cultures.pdf)

seems relevantly analogous:

> "Loosely speaking, I mean the distinction between mathematicians who regard their central
>   aim as being to solve problems, and those who are more concerned with building and
>   understanding theories."

Comment: I think one could make a case that astronomers and data scientists / statisticians are in a similar relationship to physicists and mathematicians, respectively.

Comment: I'm confused. Which one is set theory? I feel that it's both.

Comment: I am a person who is guilty of a subconscious bias against set theory and this answer does not agree with my feelings regarding it (though maybe others have different experiences). I tend to think of set theorists as some sort of aliens so different from 'normal' mathematicians so that the division of mathematics into two cultures is not even applicable to them.

Comment: @schematic_boi: Can you explain why you think of set theorists as “aliens”?

Comment: @MonroeEskew of course, consciously I realize that they are same as the rest of us, but subconsciously I am not sure I am so accepting. I am not a master of introspection, but the reason is probably the following. While usual mathematicians tend to study something fairly concrete (e.g. Galois group of the rationals, or homotopy groups of spheres), set theorists study some meta-mathematical statements. The particular aspect that freaks me out is that the objects I am studying might not even exist if I change the axioms.

Comment: I realize that my opinion does not accurately reflect the daily life of a set theorist, but the OP was asking about negative attitudes so they kind of brought it on themselves. To clarify, if I were in a situation where my decisions would impact the careers of some set theorists, I would try to correct for my biases but it does not seem possible to eradicate them. I think there were experiments in which police officers had to quickly decide if a suspect was armed or not, and black people were judged to be armed more frequently. Not all of those police officers thought of themselves as racist.

Comment: My apologies to any and all offended set theorists; I am trying my best not to discriminate. My own biases were probably formed because I was exposed too early to Godel's incompleteness and continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @schematic_boi Do you regard CH as a meta-mathematical statement?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Yes, I do. It is my personal opinion, and given that we probably can not define "meta-mathematical statement" in a way that is universally accepted I doubt we can meaningfully debate this opinion.

Comment: @schematic_boi But I think this may be the core issue (for you and many others).  We start with a *mathematical* statement, and then if it is shown to be independent, it gets re-labeled as *meta-* mathematical.  It doesn't seem entirely fair.

Comment: @schematic_boi: Do you regard a statement such as "$\operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z}(A,\Bbb Z)=0$ iff $A$ is free abelian" as a meta-mathematical statement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila sure I do. In my work, I rarely have a need for non-finitely generated abelian groups. If I really needed something like that, I would first check if it can be proved in ZFC. If it can not, then I would call that detour of mine metamathematical. I am afraid I am not highly tolerant of anything other than ZFC. But then, if you have a different opinion on what counts as mathematics, I do not particularly mind, you can have it.

Comment: @schematic_boi If there were no set theory, then you would have no way of knowing whether a given mathematical statement was independent of ZFC.  You’d spend your time trying to do the impossible, and never reach the point of declaring it to be not real mathematics.

Comment: @MonroeEskew no, why, not necessarily. What I would do is I would allow myself to engage in meta-mathematics for some time, eventually figure out what it means to be "provable", "independent" and all other useful logical notions, figure out if ZFC (or some other axiom system, but I like ZFC more) made enough sense for me, and then move on to doing "real" mathematics.

Comment: I realize that "real" mathematics can not exist without meta-mathematics. This does not necessarily mean that meta-mathematics is "real" mathematics. I have some sort of division into "real" mathematics and meta-mathematics in my head, I am not sure if it can be made formal, but then I am also a religious person though religion probably can not be made formal. So I am going to stand by this division before I become absolutely sure it does not make any sense at all.

Comment: I should probably note that I did not say that "real" mathematics is superior/inferior to meta-mathematics, I just like one more than the other. I equally respect the CEO of google, a janitor, an algebraic geometer and a set theorist, if that is what you are implying.

Comment: I also realize that within "real" mathematics, one might occasionally formulate questions which actually turns out to depend on the choice of the system of axioms (I do not have a particularly good example, but there is one result of Gabber which surprisingly for me involved a bit more set-theoretic words than I expected, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/077K). If the answer to that question turns out to be independent of ZFC, I would again call it meta-mathematics. This division is ineffective in the sense that you can not see a priori what is what but I think it still makes enough sense.

Comment: @schematic_boi I'll have to admit that I don't understand your distinction between mathematical and meta-mathematical statements. Set theory to me looks just like plain mathematics (it is about mathematical structures called "models of ZFC" &c, although I'll admit that my interest increases when they talk about Grothendieck topoi instead).

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question at hand - just as other areas of maths, set theory has room for both "cultures".

Comment: @schematic_boi: Maybe you want to distinguish between ordinary and meta-mathematical *methods* rather than problems?  Often we cannot say a priori what questions are going to be independent of ZFC.  But when we show that they are independent of ZFC, that involves meta-mathematical methods.  When we prove or disprove them in ZFC, this almost always involves “ordinary” methods.

Comment: @schematic_boi: So the definition of mathematical is "a consequence of ZFC" for you?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yeah, something like that.

Comment: @schematic_boi: Kind of like defining a language as "something humans use to communicate", and then claim that humans are the only animal which have a language.

Comment: @AsafKaragila To use your analogy, you might say that "real" mathematicians are journalists and set theorists are linguists. Journalists are not linguists, right? See, I do not say that somebody is better than the other, just that a distinction exists (just like, say, black people are not better than Asians but they, on average, have a distinct appearance, curly hair and stuff like that).

Comment: So Erdos is definitely the former and Grothendieck is definitely the latter, not that either of them is the better mathematician, they are just different.

Comment: @schematic_boi: But it's not like that. It's more like saying that some historians study medieval times, and other historians study ancient Roman times, and that medieval historian claim that Roman historians are not historians, because they deal with the prelude to the medieval era, rather than with the medieval era.

Comment: hmm, what does concrete mean when applied to a mathematical object? is 0 a concrete mathematical object? you mean something else here. non of the mathematical objects exist in real life, they all have some sort of existence in our minds, and we have a way of talking about them, but they don't exists, or at least no one has ever seen number 0 crossing the Elm street. if you start justifying the existence of mathematical objects you will find as much success with 0 as you will with the set of real numbers.

Comment: if sphere is a concrete mathematical object than we ought to know whether there is an uncountable subset of it which cannot be put into one-to-one correspondence with the entire sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, when I started studying Calculus of Finite Differences, and wrote some work related to that and Abel Functions, my professor said "I think we should get you working on some open problems, do you like Number Theory?" He didn't really see the point to Super functions and fractional iteration, and what it can tell us about difference operators on holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 3):

this notion that there is X and then there is rest of mathematics is a very very strange view of mathematics. mathematics is a fluid subject, ideas float around yielding results in many different places. partitioning mathematics into groups and putting names on them certainly has a value and purpose, but neither its value nor its purpose is to classify some of them as "normal" and some as "not normal".

for me personally, it is incredibly difficult to say what set theory is. often i have difficulty saying whether a paper is set theory or not. perhaps it is possible to make a distinction between computational math and more abstract math, like calculus vs abstract algebra, but it doesn't work. the boundaries are blurred. there is an example above where a user says that you cannot claim that the notion of being countable is set theoretic. very well! exactly the point! mathematical concepts are fluid concepts that appear in many forms and many places. in the case of the notion of "being countable", if you are  not giving this to set theorists then you are admitting that the very action of splitting math into such boxes is silly, it is much better to think that "being countable" is a mathematical notion rather than set theoretic.

of course, there are concepts and notions that fall into groups. it will be hard to argue that triangles are not geometric. but the point is that the boundaries of these subjects are so confused and meshed that you will ultimately run into problems. geometry has been connected to algebra more times than you can count. is a group a geometric concept or an algebraic concept? we can debate this for the sake of debating mathematical points of views, but not for the sake of defining subjects, like drawing a boundary around geometry and algebra with no intersections, such an endeavor is ultimately divisive, meaningless and above all pointless.

there is no set theory or number theory, there is mathematical thought process, and people respond to that thought process differently when they are subjected to it, some pursue very concretely defined objects such as numbers, some pursue less concretely defined geometric shapes and some pursue the mysteries of infinity. more people pursue number theory, why? i don't know, i suspect it is because it is easier to grow in the subject, but if you are like me then you would leave number theory because number theory never made me feel satisfied with myself, i was never happy with myself while growing up in number theory, it was like i was living somebody else's life, set theoretic ideas and its mysteries did make me feel fulfilled and happy. i believe what we study has a lot to do with our personalities. i do not like the concrete, it bores me, i like what i don't understand, i like that there is independence and vagueness and my job is to clear it. i have noticed this exact characteristics in myself in many aspects of life, in my choice of music, films, books and etc.

there are different personalities. some mathematicians are problem solvers, and they want problems you can state in a few minutes and that they spend a month thinking about it. set theory of course has many of them of various difficulty. some were mentioned earlier by others. some people like theories and stories. there are people in between.

i cannot say that i am doing math so that i can then tell it to others, i believe this is more like a personal quest, at least that is how i got into it. however, this is a profession, and we need to be professionals. while hearing things like  "X is disconnected from the rest of math" is stressful and frustrating, there are many situations where i enjoy defending myself and explaining the meaning of what i do. i enjoy giving general audience talks or write introductions to my papers. i think this is part of the profession and is important, given that the society ultimately pays our salary.

i do agree, though, that there is too much out there claiming that set theory is somehow irrelevant. but as i hinted above, most cases of this that i have encountered were expressed by people who didn't really know what they were claiming. already the meaning of the word "relevance" is problematic for me.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe doesn't apply to set theory per se, but logic is tremendously important in theoretical computer science, which transfers to programming language theory and from there to the real world.  Feferman's book "In the Light of Logic" also does a good job showing why it's a wonderful subject.

As for set theory: should it be wiped off the map?  I hope everyone would say heck no, even if they had differing views of its importance.  So somebody has to do it.  Why shouldn't the somebody be you?  The physicist Shevek in Ursula LeGuin's "The Dispossessed" got asked something like that, and replied "if there's physics to be done, I claim to the right to do it".  I read that in high school and that answer has been good enough for me ever since.

Comment: "In the Light of Logic" also asks "Is Cantor necessary?", and answers that "higher set theory is dispensable in scientifically applicable mathematics". The book is an argument *against* the importance of set theory.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the internal perspective, but not the external one.  Is it mathematicians who specialise in other areas, or academics who aren't mathematicians, or non-academics ... ?

I can see why the latter might say that about almost any academic endeavour that doesn't cure cancer or make things go faster or otherwise make the evening news.  For the rest I'd say is just tribalism within and between disciplines.  Put any two academics in a room and they'll disagree, unless the subject is economics.  Then you only need one.

tl;dr Ignore it.  You don't need to.

Answer (score -3):

Just point at our current high-technological society and say:

*None of this would be possible without extensive work on mathematics.*

And at that point in time they had no idea just exactly which branch or result would be applicable where. We need to go for all of it, because we never know in advance where the fruit is going to fall.

Done.

Comment: This sort of argument will in no way help (for instance) the chances of an NSF grant application to be funded. It seems self serving and empty of actual content. It also does not seem to be addressed at mathematicians in fields other than your own but rather at "the general public".

Comment: Ah it was about grants. Yeah, no maybe not. But its true.